# Injecting $http in angular - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, http, controller

I am trying to make an http call function in angular.  The problem is that when I try running this on the Chrome console, it says "cannot read get of undefined."  Obviously this is referring to the http get call, but it really looks to me like the http dependency was injected, so I am not sure what I am missing.

```
angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function($http, $scope ){

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'title';
    vm.input = '';

    $scope.submit = function (input, $scope, $http) {

        $http.get("insert-url-here")
            .success(console.log(input)); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have some syntax error.
last time i worked with angular and the $http service i did something like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($http, $scope ){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'title';
    vm.input = '';
    $scope.submit = function (input) {
        $http.get("insert-url-here")
            .success(function(responseData) {
                console.log(input));
            });
   }
        //console.log(vm.input);
}]
```

Comment: I did try this, after seeing some examples, but then it causes by submit function to not even happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to inject $scope and $http in your function.  Injecting into you controller is sufficient.  Should look like this:

```
 $scope.submit = function (input) { 
     $http.get("insert-url-here")
         .success(console.log(input));
     //console.log(vm.input);
 })]
```

Comment: thank you so much, this seemed to help.   i didnt realize that injecting it in the function would actively harm the functionality.